# SAS addin 7.1 on Office 2013, VBA code to update powerpoint slides

Tags: excel, vba, sas, powerpoint

I have a VBA code on an excel file that has been used for a long time to update a big powerpoint with about 40-50 slides and 4 charts per slide, when you "edit data" of a chart the data comes from an embeded table that you can refresh using the sas add in(7.1 btw)...

The code works like a charm in office 2010, but we were forced to upgrade to 2013.
I have the issue now that when trying to refresh, the button is greyed out and it remains so until you manually click on "manage content"... So the code doesn`t stop but I get the "**There is no SAS content that can be refreshed**" in every chart.
I have been searching all over and I have no idea why this is happening or how to fix it...

I would really appreciate if anybody can help me out with this.

Comment: Nobody will be able to help you debug code that they cannot see. Please edit your question and include the relevant VBA. Indicate what subroutine gets run when you click "Manage content".

Comment: Here is the SAS Add-in page where you can contact them for an update to the add-in: https://support.sas.com/en/software/add-in-microsoft-office-support.html#5ca4c38b-9e72-4e69-80a6-11bab668051e

Comment: Manage content is not a VBA subroutine... is a button on the SAS tab in excel....